# É possível capturar dados do html gerado pelo Ajax de uma URL externa?

Tags: php, ajax

Cenário : Estou tentado capturar o texto de determinada `div` de um site, entretanto essa `div` ao que parece é gerada com `Ajax`.

Quando eu inspeciono o elemento direto na página através do debuger do browser, eu vejo a div, mas quando vejo exibir código fonte ou através do `file_get_content`, ela está ausente.

No caso do file_get_content, eu consigo a página inteira, entretanto o módulo contendo a `div` não carrega, fica com o gif em loop...

Alguma dica para esta solução ?

Comment: Já tentou ver qual rotina dentro do js está gerando esta div? De repente pode ser mais facil do que você esperava e a aplicação tá gerando a DIV através de uma API pública, por exemplo.

Comment: Vlw pela atenção, para falar a verdade eu estou aprendendo php e estou meio perdido nessa dúvida... segue o link ao qual me refiro :https://www.cury.net/busca?estado=sp ,  a informação que preciso é o nome do produto sob a tag `p class = p2 p2-resultado-busca`, toda ajuda é bem vinda... @WhatysonNeves